# Get element by id and order

Tags: android

Android newbie here,

I have an application that displays a list of items. Each item looks something like this.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/AppTheme.FrameLayout"
    android:id="@+id/job_list_item_main_frame">

    <!-- cut inside code for example -->

</FrameLayout>
```

There's probably 10-100 of these on the screen at once. I need to get the first element's height for a separate process.

How can I select this element?

Edit: It will always be the first item in the list that I need to retrieve. But, if there is a way to select each item(with id job_list_item_main_frame) individually and get it's position, that would be ideal.

Edit 2: I'm making a tutorial walk through. There's an overlay arrow that points to an image. However, the image position changes by about 20dp depending on the list item's height. So i need to make adjustments for the arrow based upon the list item.
It's in a `Recycler View`. Let me check real quick what adapter it's using.

Comment: What do you mean by "first element"? physical position? will it always be the first, or it changes position during runtime? if not, and if I understand you correctly - you can simply name the first element with an id of your choice, and retrieve it via code - findViewById("firstElement"). Please clarify your question

Comment: Are you using a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` to display this?

Comment: @AjilO. a `RecyclerView` but, it is for the "tutorial" part of the app, so it will be okay if it gets deleted or something since it will run right away.

Comment: Can you post the adapter you are using, it is there where the items get inflated. Is it a ListView or a RecyclerView? Also if you clarify which is your end goal perhaps you will get better answers.

Comment: Then I assume you must be passing an ArrayList or List to the Adapter class for the Recycler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the adapter you have a method `onBindViewholder(viewholder, position);`

In that method you can check if `position` is 0. If that is the case you most likely will have a reference to the View you need. Something like `viewholder.yourView`

On that View you can get the `LayoutParams` and get the `hight` from there.

The only thing is that hight is in pixels if I am not mistakend, if you need it in dp you have to do the conversion which is device specific.

If you need further guidance post your adapter please.

Answer (score 1):

In your adapter for the `RecyclerView`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AcceptViewHolder h, int position) {
    //position variable can be used to modify and alter 
    //any value you want
}
```

For example, if you need to hide the 3rd element you can do something like this

```
if (position == 2) {
    //do something here   
}
```